# Do I have to supply all new resource when using resource qualifier for folder in Android?

Tags: android, layout, android-resources, qualifiers

Do I have to supply all new resource when using resource qualifier for folder in Android?

I have (originally) folder:

```
layout
```

which contains say `layout1.xml` and `layout2.xml`.

Then I added folder:

```
layout-h529dp
```

Because I want new version of `layout1.xml`, although I don't want new version
of `layout2.xml`. My question is then -do I really need to supply entirely new complete set of layouts if I add new folder with resource qualifiers? I would like to avoid duplicating xml code. If I remove `layout2.xml` from `layout-h529dp` folder then the app seems to crash though, because it can't find `layout2.xml` from original `layout` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't have to supply all ressources each time you create a new folder with a qualifier. It would be really annoying.

When you create your folder layout1.xml inside the folder layout-h529dp it will told the system to use this layout1.xml when a device with h529dp is used. But if you didn't provide a second layout2.xml, no worries, the system will use by default the first one inside folder layout.

Comment: OK, I understood what I did wrong. I deleted layout2.xml from folder layout instead of folder layout-h529dp !

Answer (score 1):

Always provide all your default layouts. If you want to provide another layout based on specific device configuration you then define a folder with that qualifier. When your application runs on the device if it meets the requirements for that qualifier it will choose layouts from the folder. See the following example:

layout >
layout1.xml,
layout2.xml

layout-h529dp >
layout1.xml